# Ubuntu 12.04 installation aborts without giving any errors on Sony Vaio

Tags: 12.04, installation, vaio, ubiquity

I'm not able to install the release `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386` on the laptop below:

- Sony Vaio VGN-FE21H
- CPU: Intel Core Duo T2300 1.66GHz
- Memory: 2GB DDR2 533MHz
- HDD: 100GB
- Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 7400 256MB

I'm using the ISO "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso" burned into a DVD. I know the ISO is OK because I used it to successfully install on Virtualbox.

Live DVD boots and runs OK, but I cannot install from it or directly from the boot menu.

The installation goes through all the steps until the final part where is asked the Name, Name of PC and password. The problem is in the next step where it should start copying files and present some screens and features of Ubuntu. In this part the installation just close without any error message.

If I am running the installation inside the live DVD it closes and returns to the home screen of the Live. If I am running straight from the boot it closes the graphic interface and restarts the PC.

Does anybody know or faced the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the *Alternate* installation CD please?

`ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso`

That may fail, but it is a text-mode installer so it will give you an error that you can include here.

Comment: Hi! That worked! I've just finished the installation using the alternate version. Everything went fine in the installation process. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In that case, please accept the answer (with the tick mark on the left)! Thanks.